# как сделать цикл в PHP

Tags: php, joomla

Подскажите пжл, как заполнить столбец Регион через цикл?(foreach)

```
<?php
     $query="select f.full_name f_name,d.*
     from zrdt.report_detail d,zrdt.filial f where f.id=d.filial_id
           and report_id=".$report_id." and report_result_id=".$report_result_id."
          order by filial_id"
      ;
//echo  $query;exit;
     $database->setQuery( $query );
     $rows = $database->loadObjectList();

    $xml_data_begin='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <Author>Nurzhaubay A.N.</Author>
   <LastAuthor>Radmin</LastAuthor>
   <Created>1980-02-15T00:00:01Z</Created>
   <Version>12.00</Version>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
   <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Result">';
    $xml_data_end='<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>';
    if (ob_get_level()) {ob_end_clean();}
//    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee.xml");
    echo $xml_data_begin;
//Наименование столбца(Колонка-РЕГИОН)
      echo '<Table x:FullColumns="1"   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
      <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding("Регион", "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
      </Table>';
//Для каждого региона из запроса в БД ($query)
foreach($rows as $row) {
        echo '<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">';      
        echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(trim($row->F_NAME), "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';
        echo '</Row>\n';
    }   

        echo $xml_data_end;
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: А что выдает $rows если его посмотреть через print_r($rows);  ?

Comment: Он выдает просто слово Регион в ячейке A1. А мне нужно, чтоб он заполнил столбец Регион

Comment: Запрос у Вас запутанный и по моему не верный.  ( $query="select f.full_name f_name,d.* from)  попробуйте так  ( $query="select f.full_name as F_NAME  from)
И тут тоже не понятно (  where f.id=d.filial_id )
Вы филиал-ИД  как получаете? Чтоб его в дальнейшем в запросе использовать?

Comment: У меня подозрение, что Ваш запрос к бд или некорректный или затрагивает 0 записей. Покажите вывод вот этого чанка кода: ```try {
    $database->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
    echo "count: " . count($rows);
} catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
exit;```

Comment: запрос верный. Есть 2 таблицы 1)zrdt.report_detail d  2)zrdt.filial f и where f.id=d.filial_id

Comment: а насчет try { $database->setQuery($query); $rows = $database->loadObjectList(); echo "count: " . count($rows); } catch (\RuntimeException $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); } exit; – он выводит сount 4, т.к 4 региона

Comment: @ЖандосКазкеев В теле цикла замените ```$row->F_NAME``` на ```empty($row->F_NAME)? "empty": $row->F_NAME```. Покажите вывод

Comment: @ЖандосКазкеев _select f.full_name f_name, d.*  from . . ._ наверное правильно будет _select f.full_name, f.f_name, d.*  from . . ._  ???

Answer (score 0):

Всем большое спасибо!!!!

Ошибку нашел. Даже было глупо с моей стороны просить помощи((((
СОррри

Вот код. МОжет пригодится кому.

```
<?php
     $query="select f.full_name f_name,d.*
     from zrdt.report_detail d,zrdt.filial f where f.id=d.filial_id
           and report_id=".$report_id." and report_result_id=".$report_result_id."
          order by filial_id"
      ;
//echo  $query;exit;
     $database->setQuery( $query );
     $rows = $database->loadObjectList(); 

    $xml_data_begin='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <Author>Nurzhaubay A.N.</Author>
   <LastAuthor>Radmin</LastAuthor>
   <Created>1980-02-15T00:00:01Z</Created>
   <Version>12.00</Version>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
   <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
<Worksheet ss:Name="Result">';
    $xml_data_end='<WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>';
    if (ob_get_level()) {ob_end_clean();}
//    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=employee.xml");
    echo $xml_data_begin;

//Наименование столбца(Колонка-РЕГИОН)
      echo '<Table x:FullColumns="1"   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">';
      echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding("Регион", "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';
echo '</Row>';
 foreach($rows as $row) {
echo '<Row>';
      echo '<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">'.mb_convert_encoding(trim($row->F_NAME), "utf-8","windows-1251").'</Data></Cell>';
echo '</Row>';
    };
      echo '</Table>';
     echo $xml_data_end;
    exit();
?>
```